# upgrade ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: ubuntu

i need to upgrade ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04.
while executing sudo do-release-upgrade , an error is shown:

Impossible de télécharger les mises à jour

La mise à niveau a été interrompue. Vérifiez votre connexion internet
ou votre média d'installation et réessayez. Tous les fichiers déjà
téléchargés ont été sauvegardés.

Failed to fetch
http://ml.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-user-docs/gnome-user-guide_3.8.2-1ubuntu0.1_all.deb
Échec de la connexion [IP : 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-3.13.0-170_3.13.0-170.220_all.deb
Échec de la connexion [IP : 91.189.91.23 80]

Restauration du système dans son état d'origine

Annulation
Lecture des listes de paquets… Terminé
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
Lecture des informations d'état… Terminé
Construction des structures de données… Terminé

Comment: Welcome to SO! IMHO, your question isn't really related to programming. Therefore, I think it belongs on https://askubuntu.com/ - voted for closing.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while AskUbuntu and UNIX & Linux StackExchange cover general questions.

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade ubuntu distribution we can use apt-get commands.
Please find steps shown below to upgrade from ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10

Steps

1. Verify the /etc/*release* file to check the current distribution
2. Run commands
   "sudo apt update"
   "sudo apt upgrade"
   "sudo apt dist-upgrade"
3. Then reboot using "sudo reboot"
4. One PC comes up execute "sudo do-release-upgrade"
5. This will reboot and load with the upgraded distribution
6. Once rebooted verify /etc/*release* to verify that correct distribution is loaded

Please find video link below which demostrates the steps followed

https://youtu.be/9jKsGWayoN8?si=gknzEB1HrJbbKGn5